# Spring-data-elasticsearch run native JSON query

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a native elasticsearch query (in form of a JSON). It's quite complicated, so I don't want to rewrite it into Java code.

```json
{
   "query": {
       "bool": { ... }
   },
   "sort": {
       "_script": { ... }
   }
}
```

How to execute such native query using `spring-data-elasticsearch` client (without @Repository and @Query annotations)? `Query query = StringQuery.builder("json here").withSort(...).build()` doesn't work, because it doesn't support custom sorting mechanisms (by script).

I've tried using NativeSearchQuery, but I find it impossible to pass perfectly valid native query.

```java
NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("query from above"))
    .withSorts(/* sorted by script */)
    .build()
// results in "Failed to parse query" error.
```